# devise reset password unknown format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-recoverable

I use the devise and simple_token_authentication. The basic format for queries - json.
my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
        registrations: 'users/registrations',
        passwords: 'users/passwords'
  }
  devise_scope :user do
    post "users/reset_password" => "users/registrations#reset_password", as: 'reset_password', defaults: { format: :json }
  end
  resources :cities, :institution_types, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :institutions, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  end
  resources :institutions, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  root 'persons#profile'
end
```

In response to a request localhost:3000/users/reset_password.json everything is working correctly, it comes to email message with a link. When you click on a link opens default view devise/passwords/edit. I enter a new password, I click the submit, and get an error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat in Users::PasswordsController#update

but in the console I see that the password was successfully changed.

```
Started PUT "/users/password" for ::1 at 2016-03-13 16:40:40 +0500
Processing by Users::PasswordsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MZVw3cwbkW+qgySSzKJLyfvNI0ZgKrG1AyTAYAQsIlQAK7mYyxoGlnlemjmajcBZz/zhL3Krmr7fhiNUqtahcQ==", "user"=>{"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Change my password"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["reset_password_token", "0733ad150b4a7d695e5125a79271f96fd7fa140d195480dcb215ecc03c048c6c"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "encrypted_password" = $1, "updated_at" = $2, "reset_password_token" = $3, "reset_password_sent_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$2uUu/Rv/c01HMxvHfDhdlunlNGejtXyVRtUQwEf2SpYOe0qlRIdlC"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-13 11:40:40.272568"], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["id", 3]]
   (12.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["last_sign_in_at", "2016-03-13 11:39:10.385224"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2016-03-13 11:40:40.292489"], ["sign_in_count", 5], ["updated_at", "2016-03-13 11:40:40.295309"], ["id", 3]]
   (6.4ms)  COMMIT
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 158ms (ActiveRecord: 21.8ms)

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
```

in passwords_controller.rb:

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
    #super(resource)
    root_path
  end
end
```

upd after the comment Amit Sharma:

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
        registrations: 'users/registrations',
        passwords: 'users/passwords'
  }
  devise_scope :user do
    post "users/reset_password" => "users/registrations#reset_password", as: 'reset_password'
  end

  resources :cities, :institution_types do
    resources :institutions, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  end
  resources :institutions, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
    resources :proposals, only: [:index, :create]
  end
  get 'institutions/:id/check' => 'institutions#check', as: 'check_path'
  root 'persons#profile'
end
```

I get the same error:

```
Started PUT "/users/password" for ::1 at 2016-03-14 17:23:32 +0500
Processing by Users::PasswordsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QT+j6cLGLyZ1NU3V8aNcXmsmPEAaXxlWizhkaC1z8DqNq85ft6bHNgFKW0r26OzOUjLEPzoYVIQ0khFycRQbxg==", "user"=>{"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Change my password"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["reset_password_token", "2a2c916a0611f1944c36f27643edc322e2625284ebf189083774832ac66ee90b"]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "encrypted_password" = $1, "updated_at" = $2, "reset_password_token" = $3, "reset_password_sent_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$5wrUqD9gr.ZF990WcScPJuzT9ftwxg6xqptkLCKugeQfbrjoQd.5C"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-14 12:23:32.247207"], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["id", 3]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "sign_in_count" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["current_sign_in_at", "2016-03-14 12:23:32.252785"], ["sign_in_count", 2], ["updated_at", "2016-03-14 12:23:32.253976"], ["id", 3]]
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 97ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
```

Comment: Replace this `defaults: { format: :json }` with `, defaults: { format: %w{json html} }` and try or remove this from routes and try

Comment: @AmitSharma, I changed routes, but get the same error. The entire text does not fit in a comment, so I added in the question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turned out that I had not noticed in his application_controller.rb line respond_to: json.
in application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    respond_to :json
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
    acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User, fallback: :none

end
```